# How to validate form in cakephp 2.7.5 using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.7

I have EmployeesController and Employee Model,and In Employees view this is add_emp.ctp view.I use dialog box for adding employee details so i want to validate using client side validation in cakephp

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('Employee');
echo $this->Form->input('empname', array('label' => 'Employee Name','id'=>'empname'));
echo $this->Form->label('Current Address');
echo $this->Form->textarea('empadd');
echo $this->Form->input('empmobile', array('label' => 'Mobile No.'));
echo $this->Form->input('empemail', array('label' => 'Email Address'));
echo "Select Gender:";
$option =  array ("Male" => "Male", "Female" => "Female");

echo $this->Form->input('empgender', array('type' => 'radio',
                                           'options' =>  $option,
                                          'label' => true,
                                          "legend" => false
                                         )
                                    );
echo $this->Form->button('Submit', array( 'class' => 'button'));
echo $this->Html->link("Cancel", array('controller' => 'employees','action'=> 'index'), array( 'class' => 'button'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```